# Creating shortcuts on desktop for applications

Tags: shortcuts, .desktop, matlab

I know there are many questions about this. I tried to follow some of them but I could not succeed at it.

So I installed Matlab R2014 on `/opt/MATLAB/R2014` and it runs fine when I execute its shell from the terminal:

```
/opt/MATLAB/R2014a/bin$ ./matlab
```

Now I want to add a shortcut to desktop so I made `matlab.desktop` and I put the following content in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Matlab R2014
Comment=Run MATLAB to do some amazing stuff!
Exec=/opt/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/matlab
Icon=/opt/MATLAB/R2014a/toolbox/shared/dastudio/resources/Matlabicon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

I also changed the file type to executable. But when I click on, the matlab launcher pops up but disappears within a second or two.

Also, the shortcut does not show the icon that I have specified for it.

What can be wrong?

Comment: What's `matlab.sh`? Your first example uses `./matlab`.

Comment: @terdon You are right. I removed the `.sh` now the matlab launcher pops up but dissapears with no result...still can not run it using the shortcut.

Comment: OK, please also [edit] your question and clarify whether it works if you launch _from your $HOME directory_ using `/opt/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/matlab`. I'm guessing the way it's set up requires it to be launched from the directory where the script is located. A possible workaround would be to write a little script that just contains `cd /opt/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/ && ./matlab` and then point your `.desktop` file to that. Let me know if it works and I can post an answer.

Comment: @terdon well to be honest i don't know how and where to write that little script that you are pointing. any help?

Comment: Sure but first, did you try running it from the command line as I suggested? Does it work if you're not in `/opt/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/` and simply execute `/opt/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/matlab` from your home directory?

Comment: @terdon yes it works fine if i run that file from home directory

Comment: Ah, in that case my workaround will probably not change anything. I've never used matlab but I know it has an interpreter. Could you need the terminal in order to run it? Perhaps changing `Terminal=false` to `true` would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552872/creating-shortcuts-on-desktop-for-applications/552901#comment758260_552901), `matlab` needs to be run in a terminal. This means that setting `Terminal` to `true` should make the shortcut work:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Matlab R2014
Comment=Run MATLAB to do some amazing stuff!
Exec=/home/saeid/bin/matlab.sh
Icon=matlab
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

For the icon to be recognized, you need to habe an icon called `matlab.png` in either your `~/.icons` folder or the system-wide `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/NNxNN/apps/` folder. The Ns are the various icon resolutions.

Comment: Setting `Terminal=true` did the trick. I guess it was necessary although I dont see any output in the terminal. Thanks for the help (you may edit your answer and put what you said in the comment to my question). Also do you have any idea why does the shortcut does no show the icon that I assigned to it?

Comment: @Saeid87 done. To get the icon recognized, save it as `matlab.png` in `~/.icons` and then point the `.desktop` file to `matlab` (no extension). I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks everything works as expected now :P and I have finally learnt how to add shortcuts! I dont know why the Ubuntu developers make it easier....like windoze with a single click!

Comment: @Saeid87 they do. Had you installed open source software (like R) instead of something proprietary (like `matlab`), it would have come as a package and with a ready shortcut file. In any case, creating a shortcut is as simple as `ln foo bar`, you're the one who wants to complicate things by running in a GUI and fiddling with `.desktop` files :P